# Google Cloud GKE evictable vs non-evictable memory

Tags: memory, google-kubernetes-engine, monitoring

we have few pods inside Google Cloud K8S GKE and google metrics is reporting high memory usage in some of them but I cannot find why. Inside pod everything looks fine.
We are using GKE version 1.21.13-gke.900
[image]